# Shortkey doesn't work when v-textarea is focused

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a small problem. The shortkey (plugin) cannot be executed on the buttons once textarea has focus.

... => Non-relevant content

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-textarea ... />
        <div>
            <v-btn
             v-shortkey="['esc']"
             @shortkey="abort"
            >
            ...
            </v-btn>
             <v-btn
              v-shortcut="['alt', 'enter']"
              @shortkey="confirm"
             >
             </v-btn>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    methods: {
        abort() {
            console.log('aborted')
        }

        confirm() {
            console.log('confirmed')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Both methods never executed when you are focused. Does anybody have a solution?

I want to execute confirm method if you click 'alt' and 'enter', even focused on textarea.
I want to execute abort method if you click 'esc', even focused on textarea.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add an event listener in the js part of the compoenent.

[This](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/capture-keypress-for-all-keys/14560) will catch  all keys pressed on the keyboard you can check what key is pressed with the parameter that comes with the event.

**Caution** this will listen to all key presses not only when focused on button/textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyup event handler to do this. Like this:

```
<textarea @keyup.esc="abort" @keyup.alt.enter="confirm" />
```

You can see more examples [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#key-modifiers).
And you can also create custom key modifiers, see [here](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/keycode-modifiers.html)